# With what command is possible know the mainboard requirements about the RAM?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, command, hardware, ram

For a computer and/or laptop used for developing and as server purposes, of course, it according with the hardware itself.

**Question**

With what command is possible know the **mainboard** *requirements* about the RAM? It such as:

- DDR type
- MHz
- `ECC` or `non-UCC`
- `Buffered` or `Unbuffered`

**Goal**

Confirm that *all* the Mobo requirements were matched by the installed RAM, according with my understanding the `dmidecode` command covers the current RAM installed.

Therefore, for example, about the `MHz` is need it to detect if the installed RAM, , is *downgraded* due if it has a higher frequency than the Mainboard's requested. For example if the Mobo requests 1333MHz and the RAM has 1600MHz, so the latter is *downgraded* because the former only can work with 1333MHz.

Comment: The question and the wording used are almost entirely wrong. Maybe English is not your native language, I don't know. The motherboard doesn't have "requirements" about the RAM, it only specifies what type of RAM is supported. And then the memory controller has been part of the CPU for over a decade now thus what CPU supports is a lot more relevant. The motherboard may only limit the amount of RAM being installed and its maximum clocks.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov yes - it is about "_it only specifies what type of RAM is supported_" ...

Comment: Again, it's only the type of RAM that is relevant. Supported RAM speeds **mostly** come from your CPU, not motherboard. And when we are talking about exceeding JEDEC specifications, that is on your motherboard and CPU. Consult with your motherboard OEM website, not `dmidecode`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion, but since some manuals indicates the Mobo's specs about the RAM supported and of course they are inserted in the Mobo ... I assumed and wrote the question in that way.

Comment: `dmidecode`/`lshw` show only what's installed and at what speed it's running. These utils won't tell you what your motherboard supports or not.

Comment: So there is no a way, right? Or exists a command that can consult the mentioned CPU? ...

Comment: No way, right. Consult with your motherboard manual (tech specs) and CPU specs. For instance to use ECC memory, both motherboard and CPU must support it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov consider to merge your comments as an answer to mark it as valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
dmidecode -t 2
```

Done as root (or `sudo dmidecode -t 2`) will print out enough main board info.

From there you have to go to the motherboard manufacturer documentation (website) for that model main board to determine its RAM compatibility.  Linux does not provide a database telling you that information.

To show information on all RAM DIMM's currently installed :

```
dmidecode --type 17
```

Also, the `lshw > lshw_output.txt` command can provide a lot of useful info of that nature as well; pipe that output to a text file it's a lot.

Comment: Or `-t baseboard`, `-t memory`

Comment: A wrong answer for the wrong question.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm confused. Your earlier comments indicate that you need to consult with the motherboard OEM to see what RAM is supported. This answer gives the info on which OEM to contact and with what specific info is required for an answer. This just seems to be an elaboration on those comments.