# How to view the hardware in Debian 12 on a PC, namely the motherboard through the terminal?

Tags: linux, debian

PASSED THROUGH GOOGLE TRANSLATE:

What command can you use to find out your PC hardware in Debian 12? I'm especially interested in the motherboard...

ORIGINAL QUESTION

Как посмотреть оборудование в Debian 12 на пк, а именно - материнскую плату через терминал?

Какаой командой можно узнать оборудование пк в Debian 12? Особенно интересует - материнская плата...

Comment: FYI, I translated your question into English via google.  The command you want is `dmidecode`

Comment: @StephenHarris please don't post answers as comments. If you went to the trouble of translating this, presumably you feel it is worth keeping and having answered. So please do answer it and don't just leave a comment which will leave the question marked as unanswered, cannot be voted on and might discourage others from posting an actual answer. Also, please note that machine translations of other user's questions [are actively discouraged](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5916/22222).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With what command is possible know the mainboard requirements about the RAM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757973/with-what-command-is-possible-know-the-mainboard-requirements-about-the-ram) - it mentions both `dmidecode` that @StephenHarris mentioned and `lshw`, which would have been my weapon of choice.

Comment: @terdon I translated it because I wanted to verify it wasn't spam (if it was then I would have reported it).  Since I'd gone to the effort I updated the question so other people wouldn't have to replicate that work.  If the  question was already in English then I wouldn't even have opened it.